# base64 decode and byte negotiate string

Tags: python, python-2.7, decode

I have base64 encoded string `sZCLmg==` which is `Note`. What I am trying to do is to decode it with base64 and then use bytes negotiation to get string `Note` back.

```
import base64
encoded = 'sZCLmg==' #sZCLmg==  Note
data = base64.b64decode(encoded)
print data

mylist = []
mylist.append(data)
#print mylist[0][0]
bytes = mylist[0][0]
print (bytes ^ 0xFF)
```

but I am getting error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xb1'
Any idea please what am I doing wrong to get original string `Note`?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct encoded string? I'm getting `Tm90ZQ==` for `Note`

Comment: @TheGamer007, apparently the bytes were negated before Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python2, iterating over the literal `'\xb1\x90\x8b\x9a'` produces strings, not bytes.

One solution would be to use a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray).

```
>>> ba = bytearray(data)
>>> ''.join(chr(x ^ 0xFF) for x in ba)
'Note'
```

As @wovano points out in the comments, also it's possible to do this without using a bytearray, like this:

```
''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ 0xFF) for x in data)
```

Comment: Yes, it results in strings, which cannot be xor'ed with 0xFF. But using `bytearray` is not necessary. The following gives the same result: `''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ 0xFF) for x in data)`.